# Dock Changeset Details dialog into a tab?

Tags: tfs, docking, changeset

In TFS 2010, is there a way to dock Changeset Details dialog into a tab so that I can browse through changeset quickly like SVN? As of now, I have to click on a changeset to see the details in a dialog and then close it and click on another.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is not possible now. You can post your suggestion to Microsoft at https://connect.microsoft.com/visualstudio

However you can look at the Attrice TFS Sidekicks - http://www.attrice.info/cm/tfs/ - which might give you the functionality you are looking for.